# how to adjust the font size of disassembly view when debuging C++ project in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, view, fonts, size, disassembly

As the title, How to adjust the font size of disassembly view when debuging C++ project in vscode?

Like the following pic, the left window is for source code view, and right is disassembly view.

The font size is too large of disassembly view.

[screen snapshot for this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4Ous.png)

I have not found any config item about the font size of disassembly view in vscode setting.